# Script that creates X text files with a increment text

Tags: python

I need some help. I want to create a python script that create an determinated number of text files with some text, that is incremented by 1 each time. For example, i want to create the text file named 1.px that has in the text " This is the text file number 1", and after that a file named 2.px that has in the text " This is the text file number 2", and so long. I can't really think on how to do it, as my python knowledge is really bad. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this site](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) for information on how to create a text file and write content to it.
To auto-increment, you need to loop through whatever numbers you wish using a `for` loop. Take a look at the Python documentation to see how to do that.

You can then get the value from the `for` loop to write in the file - along with any additional information you want.

Answer (score 1):

Run a loop from `1` to `n`. In each iteration open a file with the number and write your desired text. And don't forget to close the file when you are done.

```
n = 10
for i in range(1, n+1):
    file = open(str(i) + ".px", "w")
    file.write("This is the file number " + str(i))
    file.close()
```

Learn from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_files_io.htm) how to read from and write to files in python.

Comment: But with this script I have to create the file prior right?

Comment: @pedroribeiro98 you will create a file in every iteration. This script will create 10 files.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Also, if I want to repete the number between the text. For example "File number 1. Number 1 file", how could I do it?

Comment: @pedroribeiro98 Just add another line before closing the file like this - `file.write("Your desired text")`.

Comment: @pedroribeiro98 Please go through the tutorial link I have provided above. It's clearly described there. You need to use `\n` to write to the next line if the length of the line is smaller than a line.

Answer (score 0):

This will be enough to get that done!

```
for i in range(10):
    file = open("{}.px".format(i),"w")
    file.write("This is file {}".format(i))
```